# Airport Express with AT&T Uverse

Tags: airport

I have AT&T UVerse that requires their own modem and router built in. I have an Airport Extreme and Express as well with the Express running via Ethernet from the ATT router and set to bridge mode. The Express is having issues where suddenly the Transmit rate is low and speeds are sub- 1mbps. I've tried changing channels and various other things within the settings but to no avail. My Express doesn't seem to have these issues. I tried hooking up the Express to the Extreme (Which I had in the past, before AT&T) but now with the router/modem situation, I'm not sure how to be handling this.

Comment: Also, I have my Express set up to Create a new network that has the same SSID and password as my other router.